# Quarkus mongodb panache - Null fields not visible in MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I am using quarkus-mongodb-panache to insert a document into MongoDB, where certain fields are null. But when I perform persist with Panache Repository the null fields are not visible in MongoDB.

I had the same issue with Spring, but in Spring Data Mongo there is an annotation `@Field` which helps us write values to mongoDB even if they are null.

Is there anything similar to this in Quarkus? and if not can someone guide me how to achieve this with the mongodb java sync driver.

I expect the null fields to be visible in MongoDB with quarkus panache.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68363787/mongodb-best-practice-insert-null-fields

It is the way it is supposed to work.